# Empty Attribute

Tags: html, xhtml

In HTML, you can have empty attributes, without even `=""`:

```
<input type="checkbox" selected></input>
```

However, in XHTML, you need at least an empty string:

```
<input type="checkbox" selected="selected"></input>
```

What is the equivalent of the empty HTML attribute in XHTML? Is it an empty string, or the attribute name as a string, or `true`, or something else?

Comment: Changed the `checkbox` element to the correct `input` element. I don't know what I was thinking with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.5

Equivalent of the empty HTML attribute in XHTML is attribute name.

Comment: That is really cool! Why does this happen, though, and why doesn't XHTML work with "unminimized attributes", as they called it, but HTML does? Is it something to do with XML?

Comment: @trysis, XML by definition follows all XML rules, and in XML, an attribute specification is always of the form name="value". XHTML (including HTML5 in XML serialization) can define the values as it likes, and in XHTML 1.0, they made the rather simple choice of using the attribute name as value. This follows HTML tradition, in the sense that in old HTML, an attribute like `selected` is really an attribute *value*, and the name is implied.